# Multi column HTML list that goes from top to bottom

Tags: html, css

Inline HTML list are displayed like this in the browser

```
item1    item2    item3    item4    item5    ...
```

Can we achieve something like this using just HTML and CSS

```
item1    item6    item11
item2    item7    ...
item3    item8
item4    item9
item5    item10
```

Comment: Yes...now what have you tried? - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have tried the display property, float property, but I cannot produce the behavior I wanted. Can you shed some light into this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `columns` property:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    columns:100px 3;
    -webkit-columns:100px 3; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-columns:100px 3; /* Firefox */
}
```

Here's your [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JexFU/)

If you don't care about order, the more compatible way to do it is to use percents for the `li` widths:

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 25%;
    margin-right: 5%;
}
```

Demo for this code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JexFU/1/)

Comment: What about other browsers which are not supporting CSS3?

Comment: I didn't realize that columns property are available for lists. I thought it was only for block elements like div or paragraph. Thank you.

Comment: Actually the second example doesn't display the list vertically then starts again at top.

Comment: @strike_noir Oh whoops you're right. Uh, guess you can't use that way then. Just use the `columns` and you'll be fine

Comment: @yentup the second solution is not the requested result, if you want to do something like this, I would recommend you to use `float` on fixed-width list items.

Comment: It's not really possible unless you don't care about the order.

Answer (score 0):

Try same like this, with ul for columns inside first ul > li for rows

```
 <ul>

   <li>
     <ul>
       <li>first item first column</li>
       <li>second item first column</li>
     </ul>
   </li>

   <li>
     <ul>
        <li>first item second column</li>
        <li>second item second column</li>
     </ul>
   </li>

 </ul>
```

You will need some css trick

```
 ul ul > li{float:left;}
```

Comment: I guess he wants a CSS solution for given HTML not a solution by changing the HTML.